# Updating everything after the first character in SQL to be lowercase?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table full of suppliers names, and the front of the website pulls from this list. They have been entered in over a long period of time and have a mix of all caps or just the first character capitalised.

How do I just update for the second character onwards ?

```
UPDATE Supplier SET SupplierName = LOWER(SupplierName)
```

This will obviously change every character to be lower, but this will create more work than just manually editing the capitalised names. I'm not sure how to work in 'LEFT' with this update command to pick the second character onwards.

For more detail, it's running on MSQL Server management studio and the db itself is sqlexpress2014.

Comment: What's your database?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Some of them have their own, non-standard SQL, string functions, like LEFT.

Comment: not 100% sure, this is an inherited system and there is lots I don't know. I've edit into my question. It's running on sqlexpress2014.

Answer (score 1):

This query can solve your problem in oracle database:

```
UPDATE Supplier SET SupplierName =  UPPER(SUBSTR(SupplierName ,1,1)) || lower(SUBSTR(SupplierName ,-LENGTH(SupplierName )+1))
```

With `SUBSTR(SupplierName ,1,1)` function you can get the first character of your String.

With `SUBSTR(SupplierName ,-LENGTH(SupplierName )+1))` you will get every character after first. And if you put it in `lower()` you can make every character lowercase.

If you use MSSQL, you can use this query:

```
update Supplier SET SupplierName = UPPER(SUBSTRING(SupplierName,1,1)) + lower(SUBSTRING(SupplierName ,2,LEN(SupplierName )))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods.  One is:

```
UPDATE Supplier
    SET SupplierName = UPPER(LEFT(SupplierName, 1)) + LOWER(STUFF(SupplierName, 1, 1, ''));
```